# JavaFX Check Cell background of specific Cell (random access)

Tags: indexing, javafx, tableview, cell

I just started to develop a JavaFX application. Maybe I didn't get how JavaFX uses the TableView and I should use something different instead.

Currently my TableView displays data in multiple columns an when I double-click a cell the background color changes (by setCellFactory(customFactory)).

Now I want to access different cells of the table by using indices (column,row) and checking the background color. 
The cells with a changed background color should be stored after a certain button was clicked.

I would like to get every cell with changed background(get celltext) for each row and store this for later use in a data structure like a Map>.

Would be really nice if somebody can give me a hint. Thank for your Help.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you are adding an EventHandler to the TableCell, which is returned by your customFactory. This EventHandler is handling the doubleclick-event and sets the background color, right?
This handler has access to the parameter which is passed to the Callbacks/CustomFactories call-method, which contains the model-bean of the current row. You could set a flag or the columns name in that model-bean when a doubleClickEvent occurs.

Then

> after a certain button was clicked

you can get your info, by checking the tables items. The row-index of each item is equivalent to the index of this item in the List of `TableView#getItems`

Also have a look at http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetView.html if you need more TableFunctions.

**EDITED**

This is a code-example:

The Model-Bean used in TableView:

```
class Model {
  private String propertyA;
  private String propertyB;
  @lombok.Getter
  private Set<String> propertiesClicked = new HashSet<>();
```

The javafx-controls, annotate them with @FXML if you use FXMLs:

```
  private TableView<Model> tableView;
  private TableColumn<Model, String> propertyAColumn;
  private TableColumn<Model, String> propertyBColumn;
```

and the the CellFactory. Create a more generic CellFactory if you need it for multiple columns:

```
propertyAColumn.setCellFactory((value) -> {

  TableCell<Model, String> tableCell = new TableCell<Model, String>() {
    //Override the Methods which you need
  };
  tableCell.setOnMouseClicked((mouseEvent) -> {
    if (mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)) {
      if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2 && !tableCell.getStyleClass().contains("buttonClicked")) {
        tableCell.getStyleClass().add("buttonClicked");
        tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getPropertiesClicked().add("propertyA");
      }
    }
  });
  return tableCell;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think that TableView is actually the right control which I would like to use. But its a little bit complicated how I get access to sibling cells right now:`TableRow row = cell.getTableRow();
                    int rowIndex = row.getIndex();
                    GameStub game = (GameStub) row.getTableView().getItems().get(rowIndex);`

Comment: I added a code example, does it help? Otherwise I don't really know what you mean. Please post your code in your question in that case.